# Is there a "compare and set" equivalent for ndb?

Tags: google-app-engine

I see that there is a "compare and set" method for memcache, but is there an equivalent for ndb? I'm running into issues trying to write a counter where I'm having to rely on memcache, which is not reliable. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a sharded counter approach that updates the entities in a deferred task (or taskqueue implementation?)

Comment: Yes -- the counter works via task queues, I'm just worried about a race condition with multiple task queues trying to update an entity at once.

Comment: You can mitigate that by using tasknames for idempotence, and then querying against all shards to update a 'parent' entity.

Comment: That makes sense.. should have considered that. Thanks.